# why is an interface type not found is a Typescript file

Tags: typescript

Edit: I am updating this question as originally I misunderstood what *.d.ts files are used for. The problem is either one of "type space" vs "value space" or that the compiler can't find the interface definition.

I created an empty TypeScript project:

```
 npm i typescript --save-dev
 npx tsc --init
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "backend_types/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

I believe the default import strategy is Node?

I created `src/backend_types/relays.ts`:

```
export interface Relay {
  Name: string;
}

export function newRelay(): Relay {
  const relay: Relay = {
    Name: '',
  };
  return relay;
}
```

And created `src\main.ts`:

```
import { Relay, newRelay } from 'relays'

let relay: Relay = newRelay()

console.log(relay)
```

Now, when I compile the code, tsc can not find the Relay type:

```
> npx tsc
src/main.ts:1:33 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'relays' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { Relay, newRelay } from 'relays';
                                  ~~~~~~~~
```

Indeed, if I look in the javascript generated from `relays.ts` the function exists but the Relay type does not. This makes sense as "types" do not exist in javascript, only in typescript, and an interface is a type. I am apparently mixing up "type space" and "value space".

My question is this: I can't even create a "value" instance of the interface type Relay in main.ts as the compiler can't seem to find the type definition. What do I need to change in tsconfig.json to get the compiler to find that interface definition? If I use the `--traceResolution` switch every line in the output shows a path including `node_modules` - what if you want to put type definitions elsewhere?

Comment: Can you share the tsconfig.json file?

Comment: Added it to the post above. I believe the default import strategy is Node.js - reading through https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html trying to sort it out.

Comment: Please note that you can't have implementation code in a `.d.ts` file.

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes I was confused by that. I knew I shouldn't be able to, but vscode allowed it. So the d.ts file is not being recognized for what it is.

Comment: Probably some conflicting plugins in your VS Code. Open the "Command Pallet" and _Reload Window With Extensions Disabled_ to verify. Then figure out which extension(s) is to blame.

Comment: @AluanHaddad no change - still no errors in vscode.

Answer (score 0):

In case of using command line (cli), you won't be able to give both file option and `tsconfig.json` file (via `--project` option) which means if you provide your file `main.ts`, you must have to provide your typing for `replays` as well but it seems to be hard to give 2 files at the same time (you could find out more about pattern to include them both)

Anyway I would suggest you to follow up 2 either options:

- Put things into configuration file using `include` option:
  `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Then you just simply run: `npx tsc` without passing anything else

- Still passing files via CLI but you should put them into a dir so it's easier to pass together for example:

```sh
- src
-- main.ts
-- replays.d.ts
```

Then you run them all:

```sh
npx tsc src/*
```

PS: keep in mind, the tsconfig has no effect in this case

Comment: Option 1 yields a main.js file but it can't be run: Error: `Cannot find module 'relays'`

Comment: Did you install replays yet?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. My question is specifically how to specify where the compiler looks for libraries and modules so I didn't bother putting them in the same directory. I misunderstood what *.d.ts files are used for - re-working the original question now.

Comment: Not sure what you meant but as long as you tell tsc all files in the compilation process then it should work while your above case just only had a file main so it did complain the issue.

Comment: adding all the files to be compiled to the CLI is impractical as I am trying also trying to get this to work in a much larger Vue project.